# Compile Error For cocos2dx3.10 android

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

Cocos2dx v3.10 facing some unusual error.in compiling andoird

Cocos :- 3.10
Mac :- 10.11.4 (OSX EL capitan)
NDK :- android-ndk-r9d
ANT :- apache-ant-1.9.6

Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-15 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
make: Entering directory `/Users/Game/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.10/PROJECTS/GameName/proj.android'
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocostudio_static <= WidgetReader.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocostudio_static <= FlatBuffersSerialize.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocostudio_static <= WidgetCallBackHandlerProtocol.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocostudio_static <= CCComExtensionData.cpp
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-meabi=5'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocostudio_static/CCComExtensionData.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs….å
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-meabi=5'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocostudio_static/WidgetCallBackHandlerProtocol.o] Error 1
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-meabi=5'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocostudio_static/WidgetReader/WidgetReader.o] Error 1
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unsupported option '--noexecstack'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-meabi=5'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocostudio_static/FlatBuffersSerialize.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory`/Users/Game/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.10/PROJECTS/GameName/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2.

[image: Please reffer Img for Error Desc]

Answer (score 3):

Try using the last versions of cocos2d-x and NDK, since they just added clang support recently: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-console/pull/350

It is stated that it was tested with NDK 12b